# ADFS detect stale credentials

Tags: adfs2.0, federated-identity, ws-federation

In the ADFS management app I've opened the "Edit Federation Service Properties" screen and changed the "Web SSO lifetime" to 5 minutes.

Now I want to add logic to the FormsSignIn.aspx page to detect the scenario where the user's credentials are stale (they entered them longer than 5 minutes ago) and display a message saying something like:

> Your credentials have expired.  Please re-enter your credentials.

How would I go about detecting this scenario?  Googling didn't turn anything up.